# Zeta function universality: How to compute the shift parameter for simple functions?

Tags: complex-analysis, approximation, riemann-zeta, absolute-value, zeta-functions

I've come across [Zeta function universality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_function_universality). For a nice function $f$ in a nice subset $U$ of the complex strip between real $0$ and $1$, one can find a real $t$, such the zeta function $\zeta$ shifted by $it$ approximates $f$:

I've plugged in $|\zeta(s+it)-f(s)|$ to an computer algebra system and varied $t$. For the $t$ I've tried (some smaller values), that absolute never got small at all $s$ in some interval I tried at once. Analytically, I doN't quite know how to find the $t$, even for simple $f$ like $\frac{1}{1-s}$ or polyomials in $s$, because sums over running $n^{-it}$ are rather mystical to me.

How to compute $t$ for $\frac{1}{1-s}$ or $2+s-3s^2$? Any finite $U$ you choose.

Comment: **If** possible, the answer is buried in the proof of universality: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_function_universality#Proof_sketch.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla : the point is to show that for any finite set of primes $A$ :  $\prod_{p \in A} (1-p^{-s})^{-1}$ is an approximation of $\zeta(s)$ at some $t$. How do you show this ?